# Firebird only work with ip 127.0.0.1 and I need to use localhost

Tags: windows, firebird, firebird1.5

I use a software with database firebird 1.5 and OS windows 10

In any machines this work correctly with host=localhost

But other machines this work only if I change configuration to host=127.0.0.1

But when I try to restore a backup, receive the error "this action is only on server". Because the ip 127.0.0.1 the software think I use other machine, but this is the server.

Comment: The error "this action is only on server" is not a Firebird error. What are you using to restore the database? What is the output of `ping localhost` in the command prompt? Does it use report 127.0.0.1 or ::1? Does your application use the Firebird client library (fbclient.dll), or another library (eg Jaybird, pyfirebirdsql, Firebird ADO.net provider, ..)?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I am using a own soft to restore. `ping localhost` return ok `::1: <1ms`. I dont know. This use fbclient.dll.

Comment: The fact it returns ::1 and not 127.0.0.1 may be part of the problem. Which version of fbclient.dll are you using? If you're using your own software, then maybe you should change it so it recognizes both localhost and 127.0.0.1 as being local.

Comment: I'm not the developer of soft. But, thanks for the help. I will format the machine to try correct the trouble

Comment: Formatting your machine likely won't fix the problem. The only thing I can think of right now is that you might be using a Firebird 3 fbclient.dll, which supports IPv6 and given the resolution of localhost to ::1 will try that first and then give up, while Firebird 1.5 only supports IPv4.

Comment: Try to disable IPV6, the ::1 means that IPV6 is enabled. Firebird 1.5 might have issues with IPV6. Or at the very least edit the hosts file in windows and comment out the entry for ::1 localhost